# Java program is not run when invoked via perl using crontab

Tags: perl, cron

I am trying to create a scheduled (by cron) single Perl script to call few other Perl files to complete a daily routine job as below. The files are located in multiple locations.

```
Script_A.pl (in directory A) is scheduled to run every day at 3 am.
-> calls script_1.pl (in directory B)
-> calls script_2.pl (in directory B)
     -> calls a java program (in directory B)
```

My problem is even though the cron is acting as expected,i.e. Perl scripts are executed in order but the java program is not running properly. I managed to get the output to a log.

```
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/tree/XmlDocument
         at InputISBN.main(InputISBN.java:43)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.tree.XmlDocument
         at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
         at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
         ... 1 more
```

I have checked few related tickets on this forum as well in others and tried using -classpath with no luck. Any help is highly appreciated. This works fine when I manually invoke Script_a.pl (./Script_A.pl)

Comment: cron jobs don't run with the same environment as your user sessions. If you're interactive sessions set things such as `CLASSPATH`, you need to set those in the crontab too.

Comment: hi @briandfoy Thanks for the comment. Can I pass CLASSPATH (such related stuff) in the CRON itself as I am calling a Perl script via my CRON. The Perl is calling the java and I have used -cp to define the CLASSPATH there. Is that corret? TIA

Comment: you can either set the environment variables per-line in the crontab (e.g. `CLASSPATH=/home/foo perl myscript.pl`) or just set them at the top of the crontab and they'll affect everything.

Comment: @AKHolland: Thanks for the comment. It really worked. I added the CLASSPATH at the top of the crontab and it worked just as expected.